# writing DSL map inside map with closure groovy,

Tags: groovy, closures

Accessing map inside map  with closure, 
I have a map object the values is another map object 
e.g:-
`

```
 to access the data like this I can issue
def map = [name:"Gromit", likes:"cheese", id:1234]
def map2 =[map1:map]
map2.each{entry ->
    println entry.key
    entry.value.each {entry1 ->  println  entry1.key
        println entry1.value
    }
}


to access a single map i can issue 
    map.each{entry ->
        println entry.key
        println entry.value
    }

'
```

How can I write a DSL for the above map example in simple any hint?

Comment: It might be easier to answer if you say what you want the dsl to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an illustration of printing the keys and values of the inner map. Try this:

```
map1=new HashMap()
map2=new HashMap()
map2.put("1","one")
map1.put("map2",map2) 

map1.each{ entry1 ->
    def innerMap = entry1.value
    innerMap.each { entry2 ->
        println "key is ${entry2.key}"
        println "value is ${entry2.value}"
    }
}
```

Comment: This was an answer to the original question, which has changed substantially while I was writing. It is now a question about a DSL.

Comment: Thanks Michalel any clue on dsl

Answer (score 0):

anish, I assume you look for a shorter way to access the map, this would be `map2.map1`. You can then use `map2.map1.name` to get "Gromit". If a shorter way to get the map was not your question, then please specify more.