# groovy closure for complex object

Tags: groovy, closures

How can i write closure for below complex scenario

```
def empList=[];
EmployeeData empData = null;
empData=new EmployeeDataImpl("anish","nath");
empList.add(empData );
empData=new EmployeeDataImpl("JOHN","SMITH");
empList.add(empData );

Employee employee= new Employee(empList);
```

how can i write closure so that using emplyee object i will get empData details ? any hint Idea ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking (as with [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7461467/6509))

Comment: Hi tim,Q is how can i write closure to get the data

Comment: But what is `name`, `instance` and `int... option` supposed to be?  I think an example of what you want might help?

Comment: @Tim, i have removed that part

Comment: had a go at an answer....  still not sure if I'm on the right lines...

Comment: @Tim : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7482933/groovy-closure-for-complex-object-prblm-stateme2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean...

To iterate over the `EmployeeData`, you could just use `each`:

```
empList.each { println it }
```

To find a particular entry, you can use `find`:

```
// Assume EmployeeData has a firstName property, you don't show its structure
EmployeeData anish = empList.find { it.firstName == 'anish' }
```

Or you can find all people with a given surname by using `findAll`:

```
def smiths = empList.findAll { it.surname == 'Smith' }
```

It depends what you want "the closure" to do...

#### Edit

Right, after you have explained your DSL that you want, I have come up with this (which will solve the given problem):

```
@groovy.transform.Canonical
class EmployeeData {
  String firstName
  String lastName
}

class Employee {
  List<EmployeeData> empList = []

  Employee( List<EmployeeData> list ) {
    empList = list
  }
}

class EmployeeDSL {
  Employee root

  List propchain = []

  EmployeeDSL( Employee root ) {
    this.root = root
  }

  def propertyMissing( String name ) {
    // if name is 'add' and we have a chain of names
    if( name == 'add' && propchain ) {
      // add a new employee
      root.empList << new EmployeeData( firstName:propchain.take( 1 ).join( ' ' ), lastName:propchain.drop( 1 ).join( ' ' ) )
      // and reset the chain of names
      propchain = []
    }
    else {
      // add this name to the chain of names
      propchain << name
      this
    }
  }
}

Employee emp = new Employee( [] )

new EmployeeDSL( emp ).with {
  anish.nath.add
  tim.yates.add
}

emp.empList.each {
  println it
}
```

It uses `take()` and `drop()`, so you will need groovy 1.8.1+

Hope it makes sense!  It's a bit of an odd syntax however (using the keyword `add` to add the strings as an Employee), and instead of this it might be better to come up with something similar to `MarkupBuilder` by implementing `BuilderSupport`

Comment: the solution really work i jave posted your given sugestion and also learning groovy from your experince, my second problem lies how can i write a DSL for the same programe

Comment: THis is where the problem lies... what do you mean by _'a DSL for the same program'_?  Can you give an example of such a DSL?  What is it you're trying to achieve?  Also, rather than posting an answer to your own question, it's better if put that extra info into an edit of your original question.

Comment: i realaly got your question :-  i want my my dsl should look like      emplist=anish.nath.add //actually call to new        //EmployeeData(firstName:"Anish", lastName:"nath") and then adding to a list ;

Comment: empList=anish.nath.add //actually call to empList.add( new EmployeeData(firstName:"Anish",lastName:"nath");)                      similar to this is my final objective

Comment: you are really genius, please share me some link on groovy practical examples and learning so that i can used this feature in my current project

Comment: while adding the dsl like  4.nath.addOption it throws me aught: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: nath for class: java.lang.Integer
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: nath for class: java.lang.Integer