# groovy closure for complex object prblm stateme2

Tags: java, groovy, dsl

I have an java  interface

```
    public interface IPerson {
      Person  addPerson(String name );
      Person  addPerson(String name1,String name2);
      Person  addPerson(String name,String[] details);
      Person  addPerson(String name,String name1,String[] details);
      Person  addPerson(String name,List<String> details);
    }
```

With `PersonImpl .java` being:

```
class PersonImpl implemets Iperson {
       ..
  // and interface methods implemtation

}
```

**and my person.java looks like**

```
class Person {
    def firstName;
    def lastName;
}
```

And my `PersonTest.groovy` looks like

```
def PersonImpl   person  = new PersonImpl();

person.addPerson("anish")
person.addPerson("anish","nath")
person.addPerson("john","smith")
person.addPerson("tim","yates")
def list=[];
list.add("abc")
list.add("qpr")
person.addPerson("anish",list)
person.addPerson("nath","11", [".docsDevNmAccessStatus.1", "Integer", "4"])
person.addPerson("nath","11", [".docsDevNmAccessStatus.1", "String", "4"])
```

Is there any way to define the DSL for this interface so that i easily called addOperation easily?

The problem is that the `IPerson` interface cannot be changed.

how can i write dsl something like

```
addPerson "anihs" "nath" //call to person.addPerson("anish","nath")
addPerson "tim" "kates" 

//simlary of other interface method any suggestion
```

Comment: You have not specified the implementation of PersonImpl.. Are you referring to Person class

Comment: Also, which method of your interface is `person.addPerson("nath","11", [".docsDevNmAccessStatus.1", "String", "4"])` supposed to be calling?

Comment: @anish So you can `addPerson` to `PersonImp`?  What happened to `Person.java`?  And a `Person` can have a list of `Person` objects as `details`?  Or just a freeform `List<String>`?  I'm struggling with this code...

Comment: @tim_yates i have corrected the code again, please let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Groovy something like `addPerson "anihs" "nath"` is not really allowed. If you wanted two arguments you would have to use a comma. So the best you can get is `addPerson "anihs", "nath"`. But this method calls is just hanging in the air, the context is missing. One quite easy version would be of course:

```
def PersonImpl person = new PersonImpl();
person.with {
  addPerson "anish"
  addPerson "anish","nath"
  addPerson "john","smith"
  addPerson "tim","yates"
  def list = ["abc", "qpr"]
  addPerson "anish",list
  addPerson "nath","11", [".docsDevNmAccessStatus.1", "Integer", "4"]
  addPerson "nath","11", [".docsDevNmAccessStatus.1", "String", "4"]
}
```

though I am not sure this is enough for you.